# Intersection of surfaces, how can I find them?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

I'm aware that, if I have two functions defined with z as the independent variable, like $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=x+2y+5$ I can just set them as equal to each other: $$x^2+y^2=x+2y+5$$
$$x^2+y^2-x-2y=5$$
$$(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+(y-1)^2=\frac{15}{4}$$
I don't recognize what kind of curve that is, but I guess it's the intersection of the first two, is that right?

Well, now what happens when I have something like $z=x+y$ and $x^2+y^2=4$? What other methods can I use to find an intersection between curves like these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, you have a circle, centered at $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$.

To answer your second question, you always use the same method: you find out what you can say about the variables if you assume both equations are true.

From the second equation, you have $$x^2=4-y^2$$

Substituting into the second equation, we get the intersection $$z = y+\sqrt{4-y^2}$$ And $$z = y-\sqrt{4-y^2}$$ Any point on this curve will satisfy both equations.

You can also put both equations in polar coordinates, then you will get a parametrization in terms of $\theta$. The fact that $$\cos^2+\sin^2=1$$ makes this much simpler.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realized this substitution was also available! Is it possible that you've missed a square root and it's $z=\sqrt{4-y^2}+y$?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank-you.

Answer (score 2):

The intersection of the surfaces $z=x+y$ and $x^2+y^2=4$ is a curve whose parametric equation is: $r(t) = (t, \pm \sqrt{4-t^2}, t \pm \sqrt{4-t^2}), -2 \le t \le 2.$

Comment: Oh, how did you get that parametric equation?

Comment: solve for $y$ in term of $x = t$.